# Is this matrix definite positive?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know if and why this matrix is definite positive:

$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i . y_i^T$$

where the $y_i$ are vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. $A$ is positive semidefinite for all choices of $y_i$, as for any $x \in \mathbb R^k$, we have
\begin{align*}
  x^tAx &= \sum_{i=1}^n x^ty_i \cdot y_i^tx\\
        &= \sum_{i=1}^n (x^ty_i)^2\\
        & \ge 0 
\end{align*}
If the $(y_i)$ form a spanning set for $\mathbb R^k$, then $A$ is definite, as then given $x \ne 0$, there is an $i$ with $x^t y_i \ne 0$, hence $(x^t y_i)^2> 0$, giving $> 0$ in the last line above.